# Unordered Set Pair Formal Definition

Tags: combinations, multisets

I am stuck in what would be the best way to define a pair of unordered items. Say I have a set of items $D$. Now, I want to have a set of a pair of items.

I currently defined that as $S=\left\{ \{i,j\} : i, j\in D  \right\}$. Now, note that for any set ${i,j}$ the items where $i=j$ could also be included.
 Therefore, I will have a total of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ pairs.

For example, if $D=\{1,2\}$, I want $S=\{\{1,1\},\{1,2\},\{2,2\}\}$.

Is the definition okey? What is the best formal definition?

Comment: What you want are called multisets (of cardinality 2), i.e. unordered sequences of length 2. Your definition is sufficient to count them, but it's a little awkward since e.g. {1,1} = {1}, so you are really making $S$ be the collection all one and two element subsets of $D$ -- which may be  different, conceptually, from what you want, although it is in one-to-one correspondence with it. Also you have $n(n+1)/2$ as the total number from a set $D$ of size $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Yes, I fixed the counts. It was a typo.